# Does HttpClient spin a new thread even if I immediately get the Result of the returned task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

In my application I like to try and be consistant and use HttpClient whenever I can. However, sometimes I dont need the asynchronous properties of HttpClient and so I simply get the Result of the Task as soon as it is returned as demonstrated in the code below.

```
public HttpResponseMessage httpPostWrapperMethod(string postBody, string url)
{
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    return client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
}
```

My two part question is this:

Does this code cause a new thread to be spun in the background when making the call?

and

If my calls to this other service are taking around 500ms, is this going to cause me to eat up too many threads when the service is under a production load of around 100 requests/second?

Comment: Have a look at the articles on my [async-await curation](https://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PostAsync` doesn't result in a thread being created, no.  In fact, were the code to be used asynchronously no thread would ever need to be doing anything for this work to be done.  In your case here you're having the current thread sit around doing nothing while you wait for the operation to finish, so that is the only thread who's time is being consumed/wasted when performing this operation.

Comment: This answer makes sense. would you care to comment to the second part of the question?

Comment: @tezromania I couldn't possibly know if code that I'm unaware of running on some unknown hardware with an unknown degree of sever load is going to be a problem or not.  It's something you're going to have to benchmark yourself to find out.

Comment: I see. Do you have a simple architectural suggestion for how I could change this wrapper to keep my application from becoming thread-bound? I would really appreciate the advice.

Comment: @tezromania There is lots of information online on how to handle web requests asynchronously in ASP.  You'll have to look through some of those.

Comment: Does this pretty much mean that in the end, based on the above code, using `PostAsync` wasn't really "async" (it's synchronous/blocking)?

Comment: @EdSF When you synchronously wait for it to complete, yes.